# Take contents of a tab and write it in file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to extract the contents of a authenticated site.

I trying this by using latest Firefox Add-on SDK to make a extension to do that.

Till now i learned how to open a tab.

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');
exports.main = function() {
    new Widget({
        label: "My Mozilla Widget",
        contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",

        onClick: function(event) {
           tabs.open("google.com")
            }
        });
};
```

I want to take the contents of the tab just opened and save it to local file. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to open it in a tab first? Can't you just [request](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/request.html) the page without having it load in a tab?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I have a page that loads the content after some seconds. When I try using "request" it gives the page at 0s. Showing "Content Loading". I want the page to fetched with data, which comes after some time. Is there a way to do that using "request"? Thanks

Comment: No, `request` doesn't execute scripts and thus whatever is loading the page's content will not be in the request's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to attach a content script to fetch the page's DOM HTML when it's done loading.

I'm not sure *when* you consider the page to be completely loaded, as the "Content Loading" sounds like an AJAX request loading parts of the page. I assume that somehow, you can get trigger a function `pageLoaded` in the page's context when the page is loaded. You could trigger that function in various ways: listen for a DOM change, monitor an AJAX request,...

Either way, you can then attach a content script to the page:

```
const { data } = require('sdk/self');
// snip
let tab = tabs.open('google.com');
tab.on('ready', function(tab) {
    let worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: data.url('post-page-content.js')
    });
    worker.port.on('page-content', function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        // Save to a file using sdk/io/file or something
    });
});
```

Your content script `post-page-content.js` should send a message to your add-on script with the page's content when the page has fully loaded:

```
function pageLoaded() {
    self.port.emit('page-content', document.documentElement.outerHTML);
}
// TODO Attach pageLoaded as an event listener to something
```